# What happens when you click on a target="_blank" link on a mobile device?

Tags: iphone, html, mobile

I have a very good reason to use target="_blank" on links on my website (please don't tell me about standards). What happens when you click the link on a mobile device? I don't have a phone to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the iPhone, it will force Safari to open the link in a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS4 devices, it opens in a new "page" within safari and the new page takes focus. Haven't upgraded to ios5 yet, but I imagine it's the same but with tabs. I don't know about other platforms, sorry

Comment: same think  for another web browsers :  Chrome, IE and FF and Opera. On mobile device

Comment: Seems MSIE10 on WP8 does *NOT* open in a new tab. Weird.